# Why can't I set the background of a ttk Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: on_closing(root, btn))
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg=root['background'])
frame1.pack(expand="YES")

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1, width=200, height=300, relief="sunken", bd=0, bg=root['background'])
scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview, bg=canvas['background'])
scroll_y.pack(side="right", fill='y')
canvas.pack(side="top", expand='YES', fill='both')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
# canvas.update_idletasks()
# canvas.yview_moveto('1.0')
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("new.TFrame", background=canvas['background'], width=canvas.winfo_width(), height=canvas.winfo_height())
msgFrame = ttk.Frame(canvas, style="new.TFrame")
msgFrame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=msgFrame, anchor="nw")
```

Why won't the frame change its color? Or its width/height?

If you'd like to put some strings in the frame:

```
for i in range (50):
   lbl = tk.Label(msgFrame, text="example").pack()
```

Comment: Use `canvas.config(bg=<background colour>)`

Comment: First when you call `s.configure(...)`, `canvas.winfo_width()` and `canvas.winfo_height()` are 1 (you can use `print()` to show them).  Second `width` and `height` cannot be set using `s.configure()`, specify them in `ttk.Frame(...)` instead.  Also for debug purpose, use different colors for them.

Comment: None of these work...

Comment: `msgFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")` and use another color. i think you dont have defined a color (so i tested it with `green` there isn't any problem)

Comment: @JoeMo Normally `pack/grid/place` are not used to put widget into a `Canvas`.  Use `create_window(...)` as OP does.

Comment: @acw1668 ah ok. I saw different people, they use `geometry manager` to change sizes because some ttk widgets don`t have `height` options (label for example).

Answer (score 0):

First using same background color for all the widgets is hard to see the effect.  For debug purpose, use different background colors for different widgets.

Second you cannot set the `width` and `height` of a `ttk::Frame` using `style.configure()`, specify them in `ttk::Frame(...)`.

Below is an modified example based on your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def on_closing(root):
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.config(bg="cyan")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: on_closing(root))

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")
frame1.pack(expand="YES")

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1, width=200, height=300, relief="sunken", bd=0, bg="green")
scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview, bg=canvas['background'])
scroll_y.pack(side="right", fill='y')
canvas.pack(side="top", expand='YES', fill='both')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("new.TFrame", background="blue")
msgFrame = ttk.Frame(canvas, style="new.TFrame", width=100, height=200) # set width and height
msgFrame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=msgFrame, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]